# Regular expression endless loop

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this server where two domain-names are pointed to. So in my .htaccess-file I want to make a simple rule that says something along the line:

If you come from test.domain.com then go to folder X, if you come from the-other-sub.domain.com then go to folder Y. And this means that I'm moving one of the subdomains, so I could like to make it so it redirects to the right URL (in case that people are following a deep link. For instance if people go to `http://test.domain.com/path/to/a/page` that they will be redirected to `/path/to/a/page` in the new folder.

I'm struggling to do so, though. What I don't get is, why is that this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Leaves me, so if I go to `subdomain.domain.com/abc` , then the browser will send me to `subdomain.domain.com/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/abc`
and then complaining about that I have and endless loop. And please no smart links to Apache's documentation for mod_rewrite.c... I've read it, and this is where it has taken me. I know that the * means 'match 0 or more times', but I don't get why that copies the destination-string over and over and over...? `/test/` isn't a variable in the regular expression, is it? So why does it repeat it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you redirect unconditionally to `/test/...` then it will keep adding `/test/` before redirected URLs also.

To fix use this rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!test/).*)$ /test/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

`(?!test/)` is negative lookahead condition which means add `/test/` only if it already doesn't start with `/test/`.

Comment: That's kind of smart. But what if I have a folder called 'test' inside the folder 'test', then I'm unable to reach that with that code - right? The destination http://subdomain.domain.com/test/test/index.php can't be accessed with your code... Right?

Comment: You can reach folder test inside test because this is only checking for `/test` **at the start** and I mentioned it clearly in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

The @anubhava's answer is a good solution.

In your current version (and in the @anubhava's one), the [L,R=301] flag causes the redirection to apply so the newly generated url is submitted again. It's why you must take care of not applying this redirection anew.

Nevertheless there is a simpler method, useful if you don't *really need* to generate a HTTP 301 response status code.
Then from your original version you can simply:

- drop the initial "/" in the replacement expression
- drop the "R=301" flag

So your version becomes:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test/$1 [L]
```

This way, the redirect will happen only once: at the second time, Apache will recognize that the url didn't change, and then stops looping.

Comment: This will cause Apache 500 error due to infinite looping

Comment: @anubhava. Isn't it an _internal_ redirect in this case?

Comment: @Zeth. I'm puzzled. Can you expose the corresponding detailed error message(s) in the log?

Comment: @cFreed: No need to be puzzled. Internal rewrite doesn't stop the looping. You need a `RewriteCond` or negative lookahead to prevent it.

Comment: @anubhava. I feel stupid about of my question to Zeth, now that I realize you'd already cited the infinite looping in your 1st comment above. Nevertheless I keep puzzled: for me, an internal redirect is merely executed, not returning a new url to the client, and so not submitting it again to the RewriteRules. Where am I wrong here?

Comment: Yes it is not returned to client but mod_rewrite will still keep looping until `LimitInternalRecursion` is reached and thus causing 500 eventually.

Comment: @anubhava There is still something bothering me, since I'm sure to have already successfully faced this kind of situation in the past. It's why I somewhat googled and maybe retrieved what was "the" simple solution. And now I'd like to get your advice about it. It consists in suppressing the initial "/" in the replacement, like this: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ test.$1 [L]`. This way it loops only twice, since at the time of the 2nd submission the path is recognized as unchanged. What do you think? TIA.

Comment: @cFreed: Yes if you remove leading `/` from target then it won't loop again because `mod_rewrite` recognizes that before & after target are same and doesn't loop.

Comment: @anubhava Thanks for this confirmation. I edited my answer accordingly.