# htaccess: Redirect ANY Request to a specific URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I just can't seem to properly set up a htaccess-file which redirects any kind of request to www.mydomain.com. I use the following rule to redirect:

```bash
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mydomain.com [R=301,L]
```

The Problem is that I enter an endless redirection loop because the correct URL is redirected as well. I tried preventing this by using

```bash
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

and

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com [NC]
```

as Conditions, any kind of variation of it, as well as the END flag. None of it worked.

All I actually need is

- redirection from a specific url called **ab.xy.com to www.mydomain.com**
- redirection from **mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com**

What am I doing wrong, and how can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730211/regular-expression-endless-loop/34731260#34731260.

Comment: Is **ab.xy.com** an other domain hosted on a diffrent web server?

Comment: No, it's hosted on the same web server. I bought a domain at web hoster lima city, which is www.mydomain.com. But anyone owning a lima city webspace can access the content on it by using limacityusername.lima-city.com as well. That's why